# Disable window resize while maximised

Tags: window-manager

When you maximise (Apple calls it "Zoom") a window on MacOS like this:

[image: zoom]

Then it fills the screen like you'd expect from normal operating systems. However unlike other operating systems it doesn't enter a distinct "maximised" state. It just happens to fill the screen. This mostly doesn't matter but there is one really really annoying consequence that isn't an issue on other operating systems.

"Zoom" a window, then move your mouse all the way to the right edge of the screen, click and drag up or down. On Windows it will select the scroll bar and scroll your document.

On Mac is grabs the edge of the window and resizing it. Normally this also shrinks the window to half its size for some reason.

[image: really annoyingness]

It's infuriating! Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I think you're confusing 'maximised' & 'fullscreen'. Maximise is precisely what you are doing. The menu bar is still visible. What you appear to be doing in the gif is floating off a tab to make a separate window. Once you do that, it's up to the app itself to determine how to present the new window. The OS isn't in charge of that.

Comment: Sorry if the gif is a bit confusing - it's not floating off a tab, there's just another VSCode window underneath the top one. I'm not confusing 'maximised' and 'fullscreen'.

Comment: Yes, this is truly infuriating. It is sad to see that the infinitely large target at the right edge of the screen get wasted on such infrequent action as horizontal window resizing.